# Powershell .iso install with variable - unable to unmount properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, office-automation

I'm trying to automate some processes with Powershell and browsing here and there a bit, I've put together a little .ps1 file that allows me to mount an Iso image on the next available drive, store the chosen drive as a variable, and use it to retrieve the setup file on the ISO (which also needs an .xml to be installed properly).

```sh
$mountResult = Mount-DiskImage C:\My_iso_path\my_iso_file.iso -PassThru
$driveLetter = ($mountResult | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
& "${DriveLetter}:\the_setup_file_onmy_iso.exe" /config "C:\the_xml_config_file.xml"
Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\My_iso_path\my_iso_file.iso
```

The script works fine until I try to Dismount the image with the last string, but whenever I run the code as is, the setup fails, as the disk gets dismounted before the process can finish.

Is there any way to make all this work? (like, idk, maybe a wait function?)

Tried using the `Wait-Process` command after running:

```sh
& "${DriveLetter}:\the_setup_file_onmy_iso.exe" /config "C:\the_xml_config_file.xml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a GUI application using the call `&` operator, the call is *asynchronous* (as opposed to running a command-line application, which runs *synchronously*). This means that PowerShell continues with the next line without waiting for the launched application to finish.

To run a GUI application synchronously, you can use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) with parameter `-Wait`:

```
Start-Process -Wait -Path "${DriveLetter}:\the_setup_file_onmy_iso.exe" -ArgumentList '/config "C:\the_xml_config_file.xml"'
```

**Note:** In some cases, when the setup process launches a detached child process, you will still get asynchronous behavior, because `Start-Process` doesn't wait for child processes.